How to engage with graduate students and academics in psychology and cognitive science?
We already have this general question on How to promote the site and reach out to industry experts?.
However, the question is fairly general. Most of the experts in psychology and cognitive science are academics. And there would also be an  large group of students completing a PhD or masters thesis who would have substantial expertise, and plenty of interesting questions. Presumably this academic context creates particular opportunities and challenges as compared to many other stack exchange sites focused on programming.
Questions

So, what specific promotional strategies can we use to attract academics and graduate students?
Can we learn anything from existing stack exchange sites in their attempts to engage with the academic community?


this meta quetion on cstheory might be of interest.

The biggest meeting/conference in Cognitive Science is the Annual Meeting of the Cognitive Science Society (CogSci for short). CogSci2012 is in Sapporo, Japan from August 1st to August 4th. It would be worthwhile to have a representative there (maybe someone who is already planning to go) with some advertisement and swag for CogSci.SE. 

There are many relevant academic conferences. And I agree , if I were to encourage sponsorship of a particular conference, cogsci2012 would be the first that I'd focus on. I wonder what would be needed to make it successful, and what the return on investment would be?

Additional societies with regular conferences for appropriate audiences (just the ones I've presented at personally): American Psychological Association, Society for Personality and Social Psychology, Association for Psychological Science, Western Psychological Association, Association for Research in Personality...
